# Django not saving the multi-select option from form right

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form that has a select multiple option for a model with a Many2Many.  This seems to work but upon actually using the form if I select multiple things and click save, it only saves one of the items.

The pertinent info int he views.py is located showing where this is happening.

Also the output from the transaction is here, it looks like it is doing an insert every time.  I think I want to fore a create?  Though not sure if I did that (or how to) if it would also do that every time the change what groups the provider belongs to.

Output:

```
(0.000) BEGIN; args=None
(0.001) DELETE FROM "ipaswdb_providerlocations" WHERE "ipaswdb_providerlocations"."provider_id" = 1; args=(1,)
here!IPANM
Made a location!
here!IPAABQ
Made a location!
(0.000) BEGIN; args=None
(0.000) INSERT INTO "ipaswdb_providerlocations" ("provider_id", "group_location_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 2, '2016-10-04', '2016-10-04'); args=[1, 2, u'2016-10-04', u'2016-10-04']
Id: 42
```

forms.py

```
class ProviderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    phone = forms.RegexField(required=False, regex=r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$', 
                                        error_message = ("Phone number must be entered in the format: '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
                                        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'8', 'placeholder': '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'}))

    fax = forms.RegexField(required=False, regex=r'^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$', 
                                     error_message = ("Fax number must be entered in the format: '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'. Up to 15 digits allowed."),
                                    widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'9', 'placeholder': '555-555-5555 or 5555555555'}))

    class Meta:
        model=Provider



        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'license_number', 'license_experation', 'dea_number', 'dea_experation', 'phone',
                    'fax', 'caqh_number', 'effective_date', 'provider_npi', 'provisional_effective_date', 'date_joined', 'provider_contact',
                    'credentialing_contact', 'notes', 'hospital_affiliation', 'designation', 'specialty', 'group_locations')
        widgets = {

            'designation' : Select(attrs={'tabindex':'1'}),

            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'2', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s first name'}),
            'last_name' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'3', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s last name'}),
            'specialty' : Select(attrs={'tabindex':'4'}),

            'date_of_birth' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '5',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),

            'license_number': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'6', 'placeholder':'License #'}),
            'license_experation' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '7',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),         


            'dea_number' : TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'8', 'placeholder':'DEA #'}),

            'dea_experation' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '9',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),             
            'ptan': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'10', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s PTAN #'}),
            'caqh_number': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'11', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s CAQH #'}),

            'effective_date' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '12',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),
            'provider_npi': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'13', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s NPI #'}),


            'provisional_effective_date' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '14',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),

            'date_joined' : TextInput(attrs=
                                {
                                    'class':'datepicker',
                                    'tabindex' : '15',
                                    'placeholder' : 'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                }),
            'provider_contact': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'16', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s Contact'}),
            'credentialing_contact': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'17', 'placeholder':'Credentialer\'s Contact'}),

            'notes' : Textarea(attrs={'tabindex':'18', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s notes'}),

            'hospital_affiliation': TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'19', 'placeholder':'Provider\'s Hospital Affiliation'}),



        }
```

views.py

```
class ProviderUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Provider
    form_class = ProviderForm
    template_name = 'ipaswdb/provider/provider_form.html'
    success_url = 'ipaswdb/provider/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        ProviderLocations.objects.filter(provider=self.object).delete()
        for group_location in form.cleaned_data['group_locations']:
            print("here!" + group_location.doing_business_as)
            location = ProviderLocations()
            print("Made a location!") #executes twice
            location.provider = self.object
            location.group_location = group_location
            location.save()
            print("Id: " + str(location.id))  #executes once

            return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    license_number = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    license_experation= models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    dea_number = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    dea_experation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True)
    ptan = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    caqh_number = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    effective_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    provider_npi = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    provisional_effective_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    provider_contact = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True, null=True)
    credentialing_contact = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length = 255, blank=True, null=True)
    hospital_affiliation= models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True)
    designation = models.ForeignKey('Designation', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    specialty = models.ForeignKey('Specialty', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    group_locations = models.ManyToManyField('GroupLocations', through='ProviderLocations', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

#really think this is just broken too I really want something like the 
#screen in billings for the provider to have a manytomany field on the grouplocations
#do i need a special method to get this data together or can i do it through through fields??  
#look at billings when it boots up.
class ProviderLocations(models.Model):
        #group_location = models.ForeignKey('GroupLocations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    provider = models.ForeignKey('Provider', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_location = models.ForeignKey('GroupLocations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.provider.first_name

#i really think provider should go away here
class GroupLocations(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doing_business_as = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.doing_business_as


class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group_contact= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tin = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try taking the return statement out of the for loop in your views.py

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    ProviderLocations.objects.filter(provider=self.object).delete()
    for group_location in form.cleaned_data['group_locations']:
        print("here!" + group_location.doing_business_as)
        location = ProviderLocations()
        print("Made a location!") #executes twice
        location.provider = self.object
        location.group_location = group_location
        location.save()
        print("Id: " + str(location.id))  #executes once

    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: wow okay, where? which line? do I need a save? oh is it not the = but the add?

Comment: ahh okay, i see the issue here, my models are not trivial. let me post more models to show.  The quick is I got this error:  ProviderLocations has no group_location.
  adding the location models now...

Comment: Yea use "add" for ManyToManyFields. Your location.save() should work fine

Comment: Oh I see you have group_locations in your model, sorry, typo, do location.group_locations.add(group_location)

Comment: I think django got fancy with some convention naming again got: 'ProviderLocations' object has no attribute 'group_locations'  do i need like a group_group_location or something?

Comment: Oops, I got your Provider and ProviderLocations models mixed up. In ProviderLocations your group_location field is a ForeignKey (on which "add" can not be used) while in your Provider model group_locations is a ManyToMany

Comment: Ahhh okay, so does this mean I do it in the loop on self.group_locations.add or something how does saving work then?  Sorry this one has me confused, these models I tried to do good and develop a normalized database but these models are giving me fits.  Providers can work at many group locations, and a group can have many locations with many providers.   Oi

Comment: Maybe try taking the return statement out of the for loop (one tab back)

Comment: Okay, I reverted code back to original, and I backed the return one tab back and got an error:  `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: Is it possible maybe my models are just wrong for what I am trying to do with the locations?